# IIS - .NET Runtime - The process was terminated due to a stack overflow

Tags: asp.net, iis

- IIS 7, Windows Server 2008 SP2

I am getting the following stack overflow exception which is killing the application pool and making for some unhappy users.

[image]

We have 4 ASP.NET applications all running in the same application pool. I don't know which ASP app is killing the process. So having read:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5245601/223742
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17550153/223742

  1. Am I correct in thinking that if I put each application in its own application pool that at least I can protect each application from another taking it down as each will have its own process?

I have made sure that the following settings have been made for the application pool in terms of reporting things in the event log:

[image]

However the information in the event log is rather sparse.

2. Is there anything else I can do (registry settings etc.) that would give me more information about what caused the termination? Even an application name would help.

Comment: Look at your recent updates. The most common cause is either a property calling itself or a recursive method that doesn't have a proper stop. Otherwise you have to create a dump file and use it to check where is the issue. This might help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process/

Comment: @AdrianIftode And your thoughts on my 1. question?

Comment: You are correct