# Windows Error Reporting - Not capturing w3wp.exe crashes

Tags: asp.net, iis, crash-reports, crash-dumps

- Windows Server 2008 SP2
- IIS 7

I am experiencing stack overflow crashes in my ASP.NET application. Following https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/12/steps-to-catch-a-simple-crash-dump-of-a-crashing-process/ I am attempting to setup Windows Error Reporting to capture the crash dump. I have followed the instructions and end up with the following registry entry:

[image]

which looks correct. The targeted folder E:\DebuggingWER exists and is writeable, however even though I see the w3wp process being terminated nothing is written to the folder. What am I missing here?

Comment: Termination of a process does not always mean it crashed. What exactly is the issue you met? It might not be what WER can catch and you usually have to use Debug Diagnostics with a proper crash rule.

Comment: @LexLi I am getting w3wp.exe terminating due to a stack overflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907090/iis-net-runtime-the-process-was-terminated-due-to-a-stack-overflow for more detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows does not produce full crash dumps even though registry is set correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457570/windows-does-not-produce-full-crash-dumps-even-though-registry-is-set-correctly)